# Pytorch .backward() method without CUDA

Tags: gradient, pytorch

I am trying to run the code in the [Pytorch tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#gradients) on the autograd module. However, when I run the `.backwards()` call, I get the error:

```
cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at torch/csrc/autograd/engine.cpp:359
```

I admittedly have no CUDA-capable device set up at the moment, but it was my understanding that this wasn't strictly necessary (at least I didn't find it specified anywhere in the tutorial). So I was wondering if there is a way to still run the code without a CUDA-enabled GPU.

Comment: What is your code snippet to reproduce the error? BTW: it should be `.backward()` not `.backwards()`

Comment: The problem was that I had some CUDA drivers installed. After uninstalling, doing a fresh install of pytorch in a new virtual environment, and rebooting, everything worked as expected.

Comment: If you do not use `.cuda()`, the code should be expected to run on cpu. Why your code caused cuda error?

Comment: Because they have a bug, which is now fixed on the master branch and will be released in the new binary.

Answer (score 1):

You should transfer you network, inputs, and labels onto the cpu using: `net.cpu(), Variable(inputs.cpu()), Variable(labels.cpu())`